# How to resolve non-static method errors from static context?

Tags: android, android-studio, static-methods

I am getting this, actually its running in an old version but not running in Android 2.2 this is the code... I don't what to replace it with or have an alternative. 
 So i have added the whole code to be able to understand the real. the problem i have seen it run on an older version of android studio.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String Database_Name= "student.db";
    public static final String Table_Name= "student_table";
    public static final String COL_1= "id";
    public static final String COL_2= "name";
    public static final String COL_3= "surname";
    public static final String COL_4= "marks";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, Database_Name,null,1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table" + Table_Name +  " (id integer primary key auto increment, name text, surname text, marks ineteger)" );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists" + Table_Name);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name, String surname, String marks){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        ContentValues.put(COL_2,name);
        ContentValues.put(COL_3,surname);
        ContentValues.put(COL_4,marks);

        long result = db.insert(Table_Name, null,contentValues);
        if (result==-1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens because you are mixing up static and non-static parts of your class.

Take this example:

```
public class Test {
    public String testVariable = "Honk";

    public static String methodTest() {
        return testVariable;
    }

    public static String methodTest2() {
        Test test = new Test();
        return test.testVariable;
    }

    public String methodTest3() {
        return testVariable;
    }
}
```

### methodTest

This test will fail. You are attempting to get a non-static variable `testVariable` from a static context `methodTest()`.

Accessed with:

```
String result = Test.methodTest();
```

### methodTest2

This will work. You are making a new `Test` class instance, and you can access the variable `testVariable` normally.

Accessed with:

```
String result = Test.methodTest2();
```

### methodTest3

This will work. You are accessing a non-static variable `testVariable` from a non-static context `methodTest3()`.

Accessed with:

```
Test test = new Test(); 
String result = test.methodTest();
```

### Resolution

Without seeing the rest of your code, it is hard to give you a suggestion for what to change. The code you supplied in your question is unlikely to be the culprit.

### Edit

Your issue is that you are accessing the `ContentValues` class statically...

```
ContentValues.put(COL_2,name);
```

You need to use the variable that you created: `contentValues`.

Comment: I get it but please check the whole code, i have edited it now. Thanks

Comment: Help me to find the issue. Which **exact** part is giving you that error?

Comment: Ah I see it: `ContentValues.put(COL_2,name);`. You are accessing the `ContentValues` statically. You need to access its instance variable `contentValues`.